# In British English, can I use "be" in the past/present/future continuous tenses, like in "you are being selfish"?

Tags: british-english, present-continuous, continuous

According to the Oxford dictionary, be is not used in the Past /Present /Future Continuous tenses, so in terms of standard British grammar I cannot say "You are being selfish". According to the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/be?q=Be), I can say this if it refers to a quality that a person does not possess, but which he or she expresses temporarily, at the moment of speech. So I can say "You are being selfish" in American English, but I can't say it in British English? Or does this not apply to standard formal English at all, but is only a conversational variant? I'm asking to clarify if I can use this phrase, for example, in the  English exam.

Comment: Please link to the articles you're getting this information from. There are several dictionaries from Oxford, so I don't even know where to look.

Comment: I wonder whether "you can't use *be* for continuous" just meant that you can't say "you are *be* selfish," and that you use *being* instead?

Comment: Cambridge dictionary :https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/be?q=Be - but it is an American dictionary and I didn't find anything like this in Oxford dictionary, I am interested whether you can say "You are being selfish" in Standard British English, for example, in the English examination

Comment: If you didn't find anything like this in an Oxford dictionary why did you say "According to the Oxford dictionary"?

Comment: This is just English, not BrE or AmE.

Comment: You are misquoting the dictionary which gives these two examples: You’re being too generous.///Ignore him. He’s just being silly.

Comment: I think this question has gotten hopelessly muddled. Suffice it to say that there is no difference between British and American versions of this usage. (Note, Cambridge is in England, and while the Cambridge Dictionary offers both American and British "modes", you linked to the British mode.) Meanwhile, I think there's something else that you don't understand here, perhaps about "to be" or about the continuous tense, or possibly even about contractions? To save this question, please use the "Edit" button (NOT a comment) to quote verbatim the words that gave you this idea. But...

Comment: But also consider starting a new question about whatever the real source of confusion is here. Meanwhile, I'm voting to close as unclear and will retract my vote if the question is edited to become clear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on an incorrect assumption.  You can say "You are being selfish" in all varieties of English.

Answer (score 7):

The OP has obviously misunderstood something. It's nothing to do with British or American usage, or formal / informal contexts. The first three of these examples are all fine...

> 1: *You are **selfish***
> 2: *You are **being selfish***
> 3: *You are **unhappy***
> 4: **You are **being unhappy***   (asterisk indicates "non-idiomatic")

...but #4 is idiomatically unacceptable (except *maybe* in "Indian English", which few people deliberately choose to learn rather than "mainstream" English).

The reason for this difference is that #1 and #3 describe *static, permanent* attributes / qualities of the addressee (a "stative" usage), whereas #2 describes a specific *action, something the addressee is doing* (an "active" usage). We only use the continuous verb form *(**being**)* to refer to "actions", not to "states".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I've been speaking BrE wrongly for the past 80 years, but IMHO **"You are being selfish"** carries no information as to the past quality of the person being accused. It could be an isolated incident of selfishness or part of a lifelong pattern.
On the other hand **"Now you are being selfish"** implies the accused was not so in the past. A change in behaviour.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Unless it's delivered by a speaker of "Indian English", ***You are being selfish*** carries exactly the same implication as ***Now you are being selfish*** - your *current behaviour* (as opposed to your *permanent character*) is selfish. The only effect of ***now*** there is to emphasize how *recently* the selfish behaviour started.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose I should have expanded on my answer. IMHO it all depends on where you put the stress. "**Now** ... " = you were not selfish in the past but you are now. "Now **you** ..." = someone else was selfish and you are following suit/  taking revenge. BTW as someone born and bred in Sarf East Lunun  I don't recognise it as "Indian English".

Comment: I never suggested *[Now] you're being selfish* is Indian English - I said *[Now] you're **being unhappy*** doesn't normally occur in mainstream (but it *might* occur in IE, I'm not sure). I still don't see how including ***now*** makes much difference (and I live in Crawley, so my dialect / accent is probably much the same as yours anyway). All I see is that placing heavy stress on ***now*** strongly implies *What you **just** said / did / started doing is selfish*, whereas without the heavy stress it's more *What you **are doing** is selfish*. In neither case a "permanent characteristic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I misunderstood your comment, I thought you were referring to the "selfish" phrases, not the "unhappy" ones. Yes I started life about 30 miles from you in Eltham and now live near Oxford.

Comment: Well, your answer has 3 upvotes, but my "not convinced" comment only has 2. I didn't vote on your answer myself, but you've clearly written that ***part of a lifelong pattern*** is a possible context for ***You are being selfish***, and more people seem to believe that claim than believe my rejection of it. I can't see that I'm ever going to change my mind here. I think ***You are being X*** always refers to current behaviour, not permanent characteristic, regardless of whether you introduce the word ***now*** with or without heavy stress. But if other people think different, that's up to them

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suppose it is how each of us has perceived / (mis)understood the phrase over the years and the contexts in which we've heard or read it. Not too many times I'll wager. so too small a sample size possibly.

Comment: The phrasing of my first comment isn't ideal. As a general principle, I subscribe to [the "Humpty-Dumpty" school of English](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/12608-when-i-use-a-word-humpty-dumpty-said-in-rather) *(Words mean what I say they mean).* But I extend that position to *all* native speakers, so words *also* mean whatever *you* say they mean. Obviously we run into problems when two native speakers have different perceptions - but to a first approximation, English is what (any) native speakers say and/or understand, not what some textbook says English *should* be.

Answer (score 0):

"You are being X" is normal, in all varieties of English as far as I know. In this context, "being" means (roughly) "behaving in a way that is ..."

Comment: Only with some predicates. "You are being tall" wouldn't make much sense. FumbleFingers's answer explains the difference.